# HTML.Actionlink cannot resolve action in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following action link in my view

```
@Html.ActionLink("Our menu", "Index", "Menu", null)
```

As far as I understand it, it is supposed to point at the action `Index` from the controller `Menu`. However it does not see the `MenuController` which looks like:

```
namespace PizzeriaV2.Controllers
{
    public class MenuController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Menu
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of pointing at that action, the above mentioned link tries to look for `Index` in `MainController` - quite obviously not finding it there.

My questions are: Why is it happening? How can I make the link point at the right place?

Comment: Did you try without the null? `@Html.ActionLink("Our menu", "Index", "Menu")`

Comment: Use this: `@Html.ActionLink("Our menu", "Index", "Menu")`  or `@Html.ActionLink("Our menu", "Index", "Menu", null, null)`

Comment: Both work fine - thank you both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use This Following Code :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title","Index","Menu",null,null)
```

Or:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title","Index","Menu")
```